# ORACLE : renaming a key in a json field by oracle

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I have a table in which in one of the columns there is a json data as below

COLUMN NAME :  JSON_CODE
{
"DataElaborazione" : "20220718",
"DataMovimento" : "20220531",
"**DataRiferimento**" : "20220715",
}

I want to rename DataRiferimento to datarif

expected result

COLUMN NAME :  JSON_CODE
{
"DataElaborazione" : "20220718",
"DataMovimento" : "20220531",
"**datarif**" : "20220715",
}

see image for structure

[image]

thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use [JSON_TRANSFORM](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/oracle-sql-function-json_transform.html#GUID-7BED994B-EAA3-4FF0-824D-C12ADAB862C1) function:

```
select JSON_TRANSFORM('{ "DataElaborazione" : "20220718", "DataMovimento" : "20220531", "DataRiferimento" : "20220715" }',
                       RENAME '$.DataRiferimento' = 'datarif')
  from dual
```

Or [JSON_OBJECT_T](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/json-types.html#GUID-10062646-E36F-48B1-9F24-751B613DFB5A):

```
declare
  v_json JSON_OBJECT_T;
begin
  v_json := JSON_OBJECT_T('{ "DataElaborazione" : "20220718", "DataMovimento" : "20220531", "DataRiferimento" : "20220715" }');
  v_json.rename_key('DataRiferimento', 'datarif');
  dbms_output.put_line(v_json.stringify);
end;
```

You can create function and use it in your query:

```
create or replace function renameJsonKey(p_json    IN VARCHAR2,
                                         p_old_key IN VARCHAR2,
                                         p_new_key IN VARCHAR2) return VARCHAR2 
    RESULT_CACHE RELIES_ON (your_table)
is  
  v_json JSON_OBJECT_T;
begin
  v_json := JSON_OBJECT_T(p_json);
  v_json.rename_key(p_old_key, p_new_key);
  return v_json.stringify;
end;

select renameJsonKey(col, 'DataRiferimento', 'datarif') from your table
```

Comment: if there are so many rows, how do I rename so many DataRiferimento keys in datarif? 

see image embedded in question

Comment: @Giacomo Albanese
For example using query from your table: ````select JSON_TRANSFORM('{json_code, RENAME '$.DataRiferimento' = 'datarif') from your_table````. Or you can use JSON_OBJECT_T in cursor loop for each row.

Comment: OK, thanks.
i realised that the oracle installed on my computer does not support the JSON_TRANSFORM function

Comment: @Giacomo Albanese look my updated answer